# Flattening/unnesting a text field/array to multiple levels

Tags: postgresql, unnest

I need to flatten a text column to two separate columns. I'm using:

```
SELECT s.CoolerShelf,
       s.ShelfPosition,
 FROM planogram
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(string_to_array(shelves, ','))
      WITH ORDINALITY s(CoolerShelf,ShelfPosition)
```

Result :

```
[["8d2cf35d-5708-45e0-9cb6-acad358e0f92" 1
"5a91f7a2-029a-46d7-8440-9337dd1b87d3" 2
"521562a9-9d33-438d-8156-1e6b1874ec8e" 3
"e14817e4-6630-4dca-a188-ac71060dcac9" 4
"76967052-ba9d-43f5-afd4-b4bbe1452d7e" 5
"2e5a6fb2-071e-426b-ac55-69f16baa0b42" 6
"108f263d-ee78-4124-a94b-2c5641f90321" 7
"0dbe5016-9e78-4173-b6e6-ff3e0199ca2e"] 8
["9bd83b79-186d-4ae5-9373-956dbd515070" 9
"b6172191-fa44-436d-879d-c883e4d240ed" 10
"093b72ba-74cd-48b9-86df-7e7d9341ae53" 11
"88b6c7f8-1d23-4e82-b959-8cb3400cc039" 12
"8279d979-8a57-4595-b9d3-346f6b05924e" 13
"735e6139-0fce-4bb7-a4a2-00ceb86c9b07" 14
"0ad84c4f-e0d8-4606-b563-8b2e32cc632f" 15
"5a86f7ea-0763-4473-ba09-91398e938be7"]} 16
```

Desired result :

| coolershelf | shelfposition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |

The numbering needs to start from the beginning after every open and closed parenthesis and I'd like to replace guid values with actual numbers. I tried `UNENST(string_to_array)`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your text column uses `[` and `]` to separate the groups of guid on two levels, we can convert the text into `json` format so that these characters are recognized as array start and end and then use the `json_array_elements` function to split the json arrays. Try this :

```
SELECT s.id AS CoolerShelf,
       (t.id - 1) AS ShelfPosition,
 FROM planogram
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(shelves :: json)
      WITH ORDINALITY AS s(content,id)
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(s.content)
      WITH ORDINALITY AS t(content,id)
```